# Why does an orthogonal matrix have to be square?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I understand intuitively why this has to be the case (otherwise you could lose a dimension / gain a dimension which changes the length), but what is the formal proof that an orthogonal matrix has to be square?

Comment: It need not be square, in fact. But we then use a slightly different name to distinguish it, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix).

Comment: Any such proof uses the definition of orthogonal matrix. What *is* your definition?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Here is what my book says: 
"A linear transformation T from Rn to Rn is called orthogonal if it preserves the
length of vectors:
||T ( x )|| = ||x ||, for all x in Rn .
If T ( x ) = A x is an orthogonal transformation, we say that A is an orthogonal matrix." The problem I'm finding with this is that it starts with the assumption that the matrix has to be n x n.

Comment: In that context of $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, that the matrix is square is not a consequence of the orthogonality condition, but only on the assumption that $T$'s domain and target both have the same dimension.

Comment: Consider an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$. This maps to another orthonormal  basis of a subspace by $T$. Hence the dimension of thsy space it is in must be at least $n$.

Comment: One conventional definition says an orthogonal matrix is one whose inverse is its transpose. How do you want to apply that to non-square matrices?

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum up the comments, your book says a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is orthogonal if it preserves the length of vectors. The matrix of a transformation from a vector space to a vector space of the same dimension is necessarily square, so this is baked into the definition of an orthogonal matrix.

If the book said "A linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is said to be blah if it blahs", you'd still know that its matrix is square.